# Convert Factory pattern to Guice Module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have the following factory

```
public class AppleFactory<T extends Fruit>
    extends AbstractAppleFactory<Class<T>, TypeOfFruits, Fruits<T>>
{
    private static final AppleFactory factroy = new AppleFactory();

    private AppleFactory()
    {
    }

    public static Fruits<? extends Fruit> get(Class<? extends Fruit> clazz,
        TypeOfFruits typeOfFruits)
    {
        return (Fruits<? extends Fruit>) factroy.getInstance(clazz, typeOfFruits);
    }

    @Override
    protected Fruits<T> newInstance(Class<T> clazz, TypeOfFruits typeOfFruits)
    {
        final Fruits<T> fruits;
        fruits = new FruitsImpl<T>(clazz, typeOfFruits,"hello");
        return fruits;
    }
}
```

And I have tried to convert it to a Guice Module patter by doing this:

```
@ImplementedBy(AppleFactoryImpl.class)
public interface AppleFactory<T extends Fruit>
{
    Fruits<? extends Fruit> get(Class<? extends Fruit> clazz,
        TypeOfFruits typeOfFruits)
}

@Singleton
public class AppleFactoryImpl implements AppleFactory
{
    @Override
    public Fruits<? extends Fruit> get(Class<? extends Fruit> clazz,
        TypeOfFruits typeOfFruits)
    {
        final Fruits<T> fruits;
        fruits = new FruitsImpl<T>(clazz, typeOfFruits,"hello");
        return fruits;
    }
}
```

But I get an error in the implementation. It says that it cannot resolve type T for Fruits.

My end goal is to have different implementations through this factory i.e. bind

> FruitFactory, FruitFactory

to concrete implementations.

This can be changed to use Providers or anything else, I'm not too rigid on the approach

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is your final goal? Is it to bind `FruitFactory<Apple>` `FruitFactory<Orange>` to concrete implementations?

Comment: @DavidRawson, yes, thats the final goal. Is that I can put any fruit inside this factory and initialize it.

Comment: That's great! Can you edit your question to clarify this? Then someone will be able to answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no movement from the generic to the concrete in what you have written. You want your generic types to eventually be resolved by concretions, right? I wonder if your goals could be achieved with the something like the following:

A generic interface:

```
    public interface FruitFactory<T extends Fruit> {
        T get();
    }
```

The concrete implementations:

```
    public class AppleFactory implements FruitFactory<Apple> {

        @Override
        public Apple get() {
            return new Apple("apple");
        }
    }

    public class OrangeFactory implements FruitFactory<Orange> {

        @Override
        public Orange get() {
            return new Orange("orange");
        }
    }
```

And finally a module that binds them like this:

```
public class FruitFactoryModule implements Module {

        @Override
        public void configure(Binder binder) {
            binder.bind(new TypeLiteral<FruitFactory<Apple>>() {}).to(AppleFactory.class);
            binder.bind(new TypeLiteral<FruitFactory<Orange>>() {}).to(OrangeFactory.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently I'm using the Factory that I have provided above and I'm binding it like this bind(new TypeLiteral<Fruit<Apple>>() {}).to((Fruit<Apple>)FruitFactory.get(Apple.class, new TypeOfFruits()));

Comment: I'm not sure if I can really help more than that - perhaps you can clarify your question so it is a bit clearer? In the meantime, please check the Guice user guide (github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation). Your Guice solution should look at least a little bit like one of their examples.